# Creating a Django user model with groups and group admins

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating django website with users and groups... I'm trying to give users an option to leave a group...or A group admin can add and more so remove a user...Just like a WhatsApp group operates...How can one achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality for create two models. one for group and another for groupuser like

```
class ChatGroup(models.Model):
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    group_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="grpadmin")

def __str__(self):
    return self.chatgroupid
```

create another model for saving details for chat group members

```
class ChatGroupUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chat_group = models.ForeignKey(ChatGroup, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

You can create grops from first model and add user to the second

Comment: How about giving the admin the permission to remove a person?

Comment: you already know who is admin of the group, check with this user and add logic for removing
if you want permission just refer django default permission calss

Comment: We can add many to many field in ChatGroup of group user. I am not sure which one works better.

Comment: So, many to many will also create same table (similar to ChatGroupUser) in db. Generally it is known as junction table or pivot table. So, both approch are similar.